# Query based on a HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to put together a query in ActiveRecord that is in part based on a HABTM association between `project` and `item`. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@company = Company.find(params[:cid])
@items = @company.items.where("items.public" => true OR "items.project_ids" => @project.id )
```

I'm getting all kinds of errors here - first with the `OR`, then with the `items.project_ids` not being recognized, etc. How can I write this query properly?

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you are going to use OR, then you'll need to use a string, not hash syntax.
Secondly, project_ids is a dynamic field added by Rails - to do the same on a database level, you will have to include the join table and use that.

However, the join table is not a recognised association in Rails, so I think you will have to specify the join manually.

Something like this should work:

```
@company.items.joins("left join items_projects on items_projects.item_id = items.id").where("items.public = true OR items_projects.project_id = ?", @project.id)
```

assuming you are using Rails' standard HABTM table name